# How to modify makefile to compile changed source into object directory except for a list of files

Tags: c, makefile

I inherited a makefile that uses GNU Make 3.81.  It is overly complicated, IMHO because it does not use patterns.  In addition, it does not automatically create an object file directory when needed.  I've looked at several examples and read the a GNU makefile manual, but still not seeing something that should be simple.  There seem to be many ways recommended, but not clear what to use.  I have about 60 c files that need to be compiled into a directory named obj.  But, I don't want 6 test programs that have 'main' programs compiled into that directory.  They are in a list called OTHERSRCS.  I'd like to have the c files less the OTHERSRCS compiled into obj if anything changes in those files.  Also, if the obj directory doesn't exist, I'd like to create it.  The 'make clean' should remove that directory.  I've used ANT with Java and can get the dependencies to work, but I'm not succeeding with this makefile.  A simple example would be helpful that used some sort of exclusion along with the pattern for the c files.

Comment: Specific rules take precedence over general rules, so try to get "exclusion" by simply providing a specific rule for the exceptions.

Comment: If you're still stuck, consider setting up a model example. People are more likely to answer if they don't have to put together an example for you (which might not even be what you mean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple example, the C source files in the current directory
are `foo.c`, `bar.c`, `atest.c`, `anothertest.c`. We have:

```
OTHERSRCS := atest.c anothertest.c
```

Each of the `$(OTHERSRCS)` is to be separatedly compiled and linked into
a program in current directory. All remaining C source files, whatever
the are, are to be compiled into a directory `obj`, which shall be
created when required, and the resulting object files all linked into
a program `foobar`.

**Makefile**

```
ALLSRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
OTHERSRCS := atest.c anothertest.c
foobar_SRCS := $(filter-out $(OTHERSRCS),$(ALLSRCS))
foobar_OBJS := $(addprefix obj/,$(foobar_SRCS:.c=.o))
PROGS := foobar atest anothertest

.PHONY: all clean

all : $(PROGS)

obj/%.o: %.c | obj 
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@

obj:
    mkdir -p $@


foobar: $(foobar_OBJS)
    $(LINK.o) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -fr $(PROGS) obj
```

The default `make` runs like:

```
$ make
mkdir -p obj
cc    -c foobar.c -o obj/foobar.o
cc    -c foo.c -o obj/foo.o
cc    -c bar.c -o obj/bar.o
cc   -o foobar obj/foobar.o obj/foo.o obj/bar.o 
cc     atest.c   -o atest
cc     anothertest.c   -o anothertest
```

and of course `make foobar` like the first 5 lines of that.

To understand the key details, see [4.3 Types of Prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
and [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)
in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). No recipes need be written for the programs `atest` and `anothertest` in this example because they're correctly built by GNU make's default rules.

If you are going to rework your inherited makefile, consider rationalising the source tree, e.g. by at least not having test sources in the same directory as application sources.

Comment: This looks very good, but I get this:  woo$ make
Makefile:52: *** target file `all' has both : and :: entries.  Stop.

Comment: I just installed GNU make 4.1 because I read that that might fix the error about the target all.  When I run /usr/local/bin/make -v I get GNU make 4.1, but when I run /usr/local/bin/make in my source directory I get the same error about the target 'all'.

Comment: @JohnWooten Hi. Would need to see you exact makefile to debug that or at least a minimal example that reproduces it. Sounds like a transcription slip. Bedtime here anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [my Makefile](https://github.com/TermanEmil/Makefile)

This should get you going. I tried to be as descriptive as I could.

Edit:
To exclude a .c file you can change:

```
SRC     =   $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.c')
```

to

```
SRC     =   $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.c' ! -iname 'myFile.c')
```

Comment: How can myFile.c be changed to use the list in OTHERSRCS?

Comment: I'm not sure about the list, put you could but all these OTHERSRCS files in a separate directory and use  `! -path "./yourPath"` instead of `! -iname`. For more information, you can google: shell find exclude a list of files, or something similar